# Problems linking to my Wifi Router TD-W8951ND

Tags: wireless

I have Ubuntu 11.04 and I want to update it.
However, Ubuntu does not link to my wireless router. It asks me for a password and says "password wrong".
I tried to remove the password from the router with free access, but nothing changed.

The same pc with Windows links perfectly without problems, same as my cell phone and my wife's pc.

The router is a TP-link TD-W8951ND, the wireless pen is Tenda W541U
I also tried to update the drivers from the Wifi-Pen
I tried to install MadWifi

Any ideas that could help me?

Thanks

Comment: do you have a chance to try connecting to another router? is there ubuntu on your wife's computer?

Comment: unfortunately no, but I can try with usbpendrive on my wife's pc

Comment: After you removed the encryption, did you have to go around and re-setup all the other computers to not use a password? One thing I find is that people *think* they removed the password but in fact did not. I, on occasion, do over the phone tech support at work and this is invariably the case

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!